# Is it possible for human body to convert carbohydrates to protein?

Tags: human-biology, proteins, carbohydrates

Is it possible for human body to convert carbohydrates to protein to build muscle for example?

EDIT: I read in many articles that you should eat more than 1.5 gram protein for each 1 kg weight of your body to gain muscle, but I see some bodybuilders that I know they don't eat that much of protein but gain muscle and have muscular body. So it was interesting to me to ask this question here!

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Your question could be interpreted a number of ways. In particular, it sounds like nutrition and bodybuilding question, but could be a biochemistry question. Could you edit your question to clarify what kind of answer you're looking for?

Comment: In short, no, because proteins contain nitrogen, and carbs do not.

Comment: @swbarnes2: So body can not add this nitrogen or combine carbs with something that can add this nitrogen to them and make protein?

Comment: Just to further clarify my comment, the answer depends a great deal on what you mean by "carbs" (glucose? bread?) and "is it possible"

Comment: @DeNovo: Thank you for remark. I want to know, if is it essential to eat 1.5 or 2 grams of protein(especially whey) to build extra muscles or it's just advertising tricks and a person with normal diet(without eating extra whey powders or eating 10 eggs per day) can make extra muscles if he just eats more food(I mean he just increases his normal diet whatever he was eating before, not only increasing protein)?

Comment: It sounds like you're looking for an answer that is more suited for [fitness.SE](https://fitness.stackexchange.com). The biology stack would be more suited for this question if it was about biochemistry. I'd note that, re: the biochemistry question, in addition to @user1136's comment, a glucose load is associated with increased activity in protein anabolic pathways. This may be because of the insulin response.

Comment: @DeNovo: No I am not looking for workout advices! I asked here to see the scientific view of this, if is it possible or not!

Comment: Some amino acids can be synthesized from carbohydrates if nitrogen and any other necessary mineral elements are present. But some carbohydrates have to be ingested.

Comment: @Tak: Do you know those amino acids that can be synthesized from carbohydrates are enough to making new muscles or building new muscles need other type of amino acids that can't be reached by carbohydrates syntheses?

Answer (score 1):

Essential amino acids cannot be synthesized from carbs, but non-essential amino acids can be synthesized. Intermediates from the citric acid cycle or pyruvate can be used to synthesize at least 11 kinds of non-essential amino acids. They will be incorporated into muscle, but you need all the essential amino acids available in order to produce complete proteins that will build muscle tissue. Proteins are made from the entire repertoire of amino acids, and I don't think there exist any (perhaps very, very few, none to my knowledge, *I've checked the literature) that are made from only non-essential acids.

Comment: PS. I'm sorry the question is on hold @user145959, there are poorly behaving regulars and/or mods here, and one that is blindly downvoting every post of mine. The question _can humans convert carbohydrates to protein_ is a biology question, one asked very frequently in biochemistry classes; it is definitively not a homework question, the questioner has repeated that they are interested in a scientific verdict. It's clarified that you specifically want to know whether anabolism is taking place... And people are still voting to close the question. **Come on guys, what are you doing?**

Comment: @SPr re "*Come on guys, what are you doing*": I would encourage you to open a meta discussion. re: downvotes, I'd encourage you to not take downvotes personally, but consider them to be feedback about your answers. I don't think you have a serial downvoter. I downvoted this one, and haven't recently downvoted any other answers of yours. I downvoted because the OP isn't asking about biochemical carbohydrates, but nutritional "carbs", which usually include carbohydrates AND protein. That and the lack of references led to my downvote. I should have made a comment when downvoting.

Comment: @SPr on reflection, my downvote reasoning doesn't make a lot of sense. I'll remove it. I'm not going to upvote, though, since it doesn't have any references and doesn't seem to address the question, which is essentially "what should I eat in order to bulk up", not "what are the biochemical pathways from which glucose can contribute carbon to amino acid synthesis".